# Selecting elements and styling them with selectAll and classed is not working

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to select a bunch of lines and hide them on a mouseover event. I looked around and found some stackoverflow posts explaining that all you have to use is "selectAll" and "styled" or "selectAll" and "classed", to just change the style or class of the elements. However, for some unknown reason, this does not appear to be working.

As of right now, I'm trying the following:

```
d3.selectAll("#Team")
            .classed("lollipop", false)
            .classed("hidden", true);
```

I've also tried:

```
d3.selectAll("#Team")
            .style('display', 'none')
```

However, this is having absolutely no effect - the graph looks exactly the same. Is there any reason why this would not work?

Answer (score -2):

I just tried, and It run correctly.

Please make you that your d3 is running.

You can try code bellow:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="hello">Hello Boy!</span> <br />
    <span id="hello">Hello Girl</span> <br />
    <span id="hello">Hello Baba</span> <br />
    <span id="hello">Hello Pupu</span> <br />

    <script>
        d3.selectAll("#hello").style("color","red");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```